# The reason why the output waveform of gate voltage boost is not almost the straight line?

Tags: capacitor, circuit-analysis, boost, discharge

I read paper,about gate voltage boost,recently,and i found the output is not almost the straight line,the more gate voltage boost circuit is in series, the more pronounced the output is tilted ,as the second picture shown

[image]

[image]

Because it use the precharge and discharge of capacitor (\$C_{B1} \$,\$C_{B2}\$...\$C_{BN}\$) to boost every stage output voltage,so is it,the precharge and discharge of capacitor,the reason why the more gate voltage boost circuit is in series, the more pronounced the output is tilted?

Comment: When a single stage is "tilted", naturally all others add up

Comment: then why will the first stage output tilt?

Answer (score 1):

Weak FET Conduction (leakage) resistance may cause some exponential decay. 
Thus rising edge charge pump is higher by 370~372mV and  falling edge is less after each stage.  Each stage adds near the same amount to the previous.

### Speculation

Increasing the clock rate will reduce the slope but at some point will reduce the step rise due to C ratios and Conduction ratios.

Comment: well,so you think the reason maybe the mos conduction resistance,not the precharge/discharge of the capacitor?

Comment: Even an ideal capacitor will decay